# Developing Android 2.3.3 app, works in emulator, APK claims it is installed on phone, nothing is installed

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, emulation, apk

Developing Android 2.3.3 app, works in emulator, APK claims it is installed on phone, nothing is installed

It is a simple app and it works perfectly fine in Eclipse Android Application. When I export a unsigned .apk file, it claims that the application was "installed successfully". I can not see the app beeing installed in any list like google play or "AppInstaller".

Here is my manifest code:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>  
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <activity

        android:name=".IS303AndroidSPLSActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TabSubmenyTest"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that you don't see the app in Google Play list, as it was not installed via Google Play.

Have you tried using your phone USB debug mode and lauching your app like this ?

Comment: I have not tried that and I will do it as soon as I have one, later today. Is there any reason USB debug mode should work more than .apk?

Comment: If you got a message that your APK was "installed successfully", then it is weird you don't find it. Check in the Settings menu > Applications > Manage Applications and see if is there.